# Unicode vs Unicode representation

Tags: python, unicode

I'm a bit confused as to what the difference is between the unicode character and the representation of that character. What is the difference between the two:

```
>>> u'é'
>>> u'\xe9'
```

In addition, how would I be able to go back-and-forth between the 'readable' unicode (é) and the machine unicode(\xe9)? How would I do this for the following?

```
>>> u='bj\\u00f6rk: voltaic'
>>> print u
bj\u00f6rk: voltaic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [repr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr):

```
print repr(u)
```

`print u'é'` in a shell gives you the `str` output, `u'é'` in the shell shows you the `repr` output.

[str](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str)

> Return a string containing a nicely printable representation of an object. For strings, this returns the string itself. The difference with repr(object) is that str(object) does not always attempt to return a string that is acceptable to eval(); its goal is to return a printable string. If no argument is given, returns the empty string, ''.

Answer (score 0):

`repr()` will only work on python 2 (which is clearly what you're using). Here's a more complete answer, and a recommendation: **If you'll be working with unicode, switch to python 3 if at all possible.** There's no good reason to try to make sense of how python 2 handles text encodings, when the improvements in python 3 are one of the major reasons it exists.

> What's the difference between the two:
>
> ```
> u'é' 
> u'\xe9'
> ```

These are two ways to specify the same string to python; there *is* no difference in the content of these two strings:

```
>>> u'é' == u'\xe9'
True
```

Just like the byte with value 62 is `A` in ascii (`chr(62) == "A"), unicode characters have a (usually) 16-bit value that is conventionally written in hexadecimal. For a single-character, you could display this value in decimal with`ord()` (though that's not too useful).

When you print your string, python will try to display it. When you convert it with `repr()`, python will show you the character itself or an escaped form, depending on whether it could be used in a literal string. In python 3, `repr('é')` is just `'é'` since it can appear in string literals. To see your text as a sequence of 16-bit unicode codepoints, you should do this (works in python 2 or 3):

```
>>> text = u'e'
>>> print(text.encode("raw_unicode_escape"))
b'\xe9'
```

Here's a longer example (on python 3):

```
>>> text = "neé"
>>> repr(text)
"'neé'"
>>> text.encode("raw_unicode_escape")
b'ne\xe9'
>>> text.encode("utf-8")
b'ne\xc3\xa9'
```

Note that UTF-8 encodes `é` as a two-byte sequence. UTF-8 is just an encoding, the codepoint for this character is `U+00e9`.